# Why the geodesic line is the projections of the integral curves of the geodesic flow?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Picture below is from 54 page of  Jost's *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis*, Why the geodesic line is the projections of the integral curves of the geodesic flow ?

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: The analogy is almost the same as with any explicit second order ODE. For example, you have an equation $\ddot{x} + \omega^2 x = 0$. You are looking for $x(t)$, solutions of this equation. You consider usual transformation to the first order system of ODEs: $\dot{x} = v, \; \dot{v} = -\omega^2 x$. You find the solution to this system with any method you like. Now, in this 2D phase space trajectories are $(x(t), v(t))$ curves. If you know them, you can easily get solutions to ...

Comment: ... your initial second order ODE by just projecting $(x(t), v(t))$ onto the first component. So this is the trick: these two representations (higher-order ODE and system of first-order ODEs) are compatible.

Comment: @Evgeny  Thanks, do you know why the geodesic flow is from the cogeodesic flow by the first equation of 2.2.7  (in Definition 2.2.3). In fact ,I don't know what is geodesic flow ...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know answer here: riemannian geometry still isn't my cup of tea. But it would be strange if this book had no corresponding definition.